# On Event Dispatch Thread---want to get off of it

Tags: java, multithreading, event-dispatch-thread, awt-eventqueue

Suppose that a method I own is sometimes called on the Event Dispatch Thread and is sometimes not.  Now suppose some of the code in that method I want to have called on a thread other than the Event Dispatch Thread.

Is there a way to run some code on a thread other than the EDT at this point?

I tried this:

```
        if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myMethod();
                }
            }.run();
        } else {
            myMethod();
        }
```

But myMethod() ended up running on the EDT even when I created a new Runnable.

Is there a way to run myMethod() on a thread other than the EDT at this point?

Comment: You can check the `current thread name`. By default it will be something like `AWT-EventQueue-0` for EDT threads.

Comment: I know how I can tell that I'm on the AWT Event Queue.  The problem is that I'm on it and want some code to run not on the AWT Event Queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You doing it just fine. But your Runnable has to be pass to a new Thread.

e.g.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
     myMethod();
 }
}).start();
```

Please note that invoking the "run()" method won't start a new Thread. Use start() instead.

See also  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: It's worth noting that using an `ExecutorService` would allow for thread reuse in the long run.